# Executing 2 functions in 1 post method

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with a registration form. In this form the POST method is calling a function to store the field data when someone press the submit button. The function name is `WebsiteForm_OnSubmit();`

```
<form method="post" action="/mainpage/page2.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebsiteForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Now I have a another JS function called `addfielddatetocrm(this)`; I want to execute this action along with `WebsiteForm_OnSubmit();`

So in summary, when someone hit Submit button both functions gets executed.

I know it's not possible to execute 2 actions in 1 post method.

So how do I do this?

Comment: `it's not possible to execute 2 actions in 1 post method`.  Yes it is.  Where did you read that it's not?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in executing your 2 functions 1 one.

```
function submitForm(){ 
    addfielddatetocrm(this);
    WebsiteForm_OnSubmit();
}
```

And your form has something like that:

```
<form method="post" action="/mainpage/page2.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return submitForm();" id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
onsubmit="javascript:addfielddatetocrm(this);return WebsiteForm_OnSubmit();"
```

Comment: Guys, Thanks a lot. I'm still a learner. I love this place so much. I'm going to try this method.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your functionality into a single function and call that in your onsubmit attribute. There is absolutely no point in putting all your function calls as string in your onsubmit attribute, because it is very important to keep your code clear. And yes, you can call more functions on submit.